# Rotate points by 60° in 2D

Tags: list-manipulation

I wrote this code, to rotate a list of points 60° about the first point in the list in 2D, but Mathemtica says: "Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded."
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: This question can perhaps be answered without the code, but as a courtesy to those who would help you, it is customary when you have code that does not work to post the code as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is the following:

```
RotationTransform[Pi/3, First[#]] /@ # &@z
```

which returns

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 5 \\
 \frac{5}{2}-\sqrt{3} & 6+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} \left(7-3 \sqrt{3}\right) & \frac{1}{2} \left(13+3 \sqrt{3}\right) \\
 2 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

after `Simplify` is applied.

Your original code fails to work because you used `SetDelayed` instead of `Set` in the definitions `z[[i, 1]] := ...`.